# How to combine expression() and paste0 to present the superscript of R2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, paste, subtitle

I'm having trouble writing about **R squared** (R2) in the formula.
I try to display the **2** of **R2** as a superscript. But I found when I use expression() and paste0() together, either superscript of R2 cannot be displayed , or the formula cannot be fully presented.

```
ISIDOR <- structure(list(Pos_heliaphen = c("W30", "X41", "Y27", "Z24", 
                                       "Y27", "W30", "W30", "X41", "Y27", "W30", "X41", "Z40", "Z99"
), traitement = c("WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", 
                  "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW", "WW"), Variete = c("Isidor", "Isidor", 
                                                             "Isidor", "Isidor", "Isidor", "Isidor", "Isidor", "Isidor", "Isidor", 
                                                             "Isidor", "Isidor", "Isidor", "Cali"), FTSW_apres_arros = c(0.462837958498518, 
                                                                                                                         0.400045032939416, 0.352560790392534, 0.377856799586057, 0.170933345859364, 
                                                                                                                         0.315689846065931, 0.116825600914318, 0.0332444780173884, 0.00966070114456602, 
                                                                                                                         0.0871102539376406, 0.0107280083093036, 0.195548432729584, 1), 
NLE = c(0.903498791068124, 0.954670066942938, 0.970762905436272, 
        0.873838605282389, 0.647875257025359, 0.53056603773585, 0.0384548155916796, 
        0.0470924009989314, 0.00403163281128882, 0.193696514297641, 
        0.0718450645564359, 0.295346695941639, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                              "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Here is the code I used:

```
pred_df <- data.frame(FTSW_apres_arros = seq(min(ISIDOR$FTSW_apres_arros), 
                                         max(ISIDOR$FTSW_apres_arros),
                                         length.out = 100))

pred_df$NLE <- predict(mod, newdata = pred_df)

mod = nls(NLE ~ 2/(1+exp(a*FTSW_apres_arros))-1,start = list(a=1),data = ISIDOR)
ISIDOR$pred = predict(mod,ISIDOR)
a = coef(mod)
RMSE = rmse(ISIDOR$NLE, ISIDOR$pred)
MSE = mse(ISIDOR$NLE, ISIDOR$pred)
Rsquared = summary(lm(ISIDOR$NLE~ ISIDOR$pred))$r.squared

ggplot(ISIDOR, aes(FTSW_apres_arros, NLE)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Variete), pch = 19, cex = 3) +
  geom_line(data = pred_df) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3","blue3"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(title = "Isidor", 
       y = "Expansion folliaire totale relative",
       x = "FTSW",
       subtitle = paste0("y = 2/(1 + exp(", round(a, 3), "* x)) -1)","\n",
                         "R^2 = ", round(Rsquared, 3),"  RMSE = ",
                         round(RMSE, 3), "   MSE = ", round(MSE, 3)))
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can provide me with some advice!!!

Comment: Could you please share your mod to make it reproducible?

Comment: Oh sorry! Please see the updatea! @Quinten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option requiring least change to your code would be to use a Unicode superscript 2, which is `\u00b2`:

```r
ggplot(ISIDOR, aes(FTSW_apres_arros, NLE)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Variete), pch = 19, cex = 3) +
  geom_line(data = pred_df) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3","blue3"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(title = "Isidor", 
       y = "Expansion folliaire totale relative",
       x = "FTSW",
       subtitle = paste0("y = 2/(1 + exp(", round(a, 3), "* x)) -1)","\n",
                         "R\u00b2 = ", round(Rsquared, 3),"  RMSE = ",
                         round(RMSE, 3), "   MSE = ", round(MSE, 3)))
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `bquote`, which allows for nicer formatting of your formula and easy addition of bold text:

```r
ggplot(ISIDOR, aes(FTSW_apres_arros, NLE)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Variete), pch = 19, cex = 3) +
  geom_line(data = pred_df) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red3","blue3"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(title = "Isidor", 
       y = "Expansion folliaire totale relative",
       x = "FTSW",
       subtitle = bquote(y == over(2, 1 + e^(.(round(a, 3)) * x)) - 1~~~~~~~~
                           bold(R^2) == .(round(Rsquared, 3))~~~
                           bold(RMSE) == .(round(RMSE, 3))~~~
                           bold(MSE) == .(round(MSE, 3))))
```

[image]